# Reducing build times on using boost graph library

Tags: c++, boost, build, boost-graph

I use the following boost libraries:

`#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>`

in my user file

`gcs.h`

and

`#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>`

in my user file

`boostgraph.h`

Then, I had `#include`d `gcs.h` and `boostgraph.h` in a bunch of my other `.cpp` files. On running `Build Insight` in Visual Studio, the IDE indicated that a large amount of my build time was being spent in parsing `ptree.hpp` and `adjacency_list.hpp` due to their inclusion in multiple translation units. To resolve this, atleast for `ptree.hpp`, I refactored my code so that my `gcs.h` file only does:

`#include <boost/property_tree/ptree_fwd.hpp>`

which seems to be a forward declaration header provided by the boost library itself. Then, in the specific `.cpp` files where the functionality is used, I had the full header:

`#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>`

This did end up reducing my build time atleast as far as the repeated parsing of `ptree.hpp` went.

I tried to see if there was any equivalent forward declared headers for `adjacency_list.hpp` but something equivalent like `adjacency_list_fwd.hpp` does not seem to be provided by the boost graph library.

(1) Is this the right approach to try to reduce build times -- having only minimal header files in user `.h` files and then having the full header file in the `.cpp` files where the class is actually needed?

(2) Is there a way to structure the boost graph library code so that build times are reduced? (I realize that this specific question is somewhat open ended, but hope this post is not closed as I am looking for specific inputs that are not opinion based on how to reduce build time for boost graph library, especially given that other boost libraries seem to provide a minimal forward declaration header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what definitions are necessary in the header.

Basically you may be able to use your own forward declarations of your own types.

Otherwise you should typically use the PIMPL idiom, in this context also known as "compilation firewalling".

Comment: I see. I will look into those. Do you have any thoughts on why some boost libraries seem to offer a "_fwd.hpp" file, like ptree, while some others do not? Can I bother the folks over at graph library on github to think about offering some such stuff? In other words, my question is, is it the responsibility of the library writer to provide a forward header file or is it the user's responsibiity?

Comment: It's not useful for the highly generic template libraries since they can not be used unless the definitions are visible. It could be argued that there's always *some* use but in reality that use is extremely limited (eg to return values or parameters by reference). In practice any interface that contains this still needs the definitions at the call site. In my experience the graph model never needs to be in the public interface, making PIMPL the obvious solution